# Is there any capacity on creating View

Tags: mysql, sql-view

Suppose I have a table having a thousand or more users.  If I create a view for each user does it affect performance?

```
CREATE VIEW vw_userid of user AS
SELECT * 
FROM Updates 
WHERE userid='userid of user'
```

Comment: Creating a view always affects performance (as obvious).

Comment: Yes it does, specially if you intend to make one for 1000+ users.

Comment: i want create view per user. if i have 1000 user there will be 1000 view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your case it is effecting, coz first query will read a table & generate view, Again it will do read operation to Retrieve data, Also you are creating **view** in run time so every time it will consume memory.If **I/O** request will be more then your server may become unresponsive. i will suggest to go with **Select statement** will be better for you.

Comment: i will create view when user register my web site and then whenever user logs i will use that view to retrieve data

Comment: Suppose 10000 users are logged in now, How many views you will create & how will it work, Just think of the scenario.Here day by day users will keep on increasing. Which hosting will provide you the support for this many tables.

Comment: If you want to create view then create only one where each row can have **GUID** as primary key & using userid you can retrieve the data.

Comment: ok that's what i was asking. so better way is to use SELECT and will drop idea for creating view

Comment: Yes! it will be faster than creating a view for each user.